# Using Redux-forms how do I supply a callback to execute after successful async form submission?

Tags: redux-form

I have a redux form that will call a rest API on form submission. If the API call fails I'd like to raise a SubmissionError so that the error can be displayed on the form. As the submission error details map to properties on the form I would like this handling to be part of the form component.

Once the form has successfully submitted to the API and got a success response I would like the form component to call a method (methodA) supplied to the form component.

At the moment the only way I can see of doing this is to:

- Pass methodA in the props of the form component.
- In the form component's call to reduxForm() supply a method to onSubmitSuccess in the config object (methodB)
- In methodB pull methodA from the supplied props and then call it

Is this the best way of doing what I want or is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0):

In the action creator (assuming you are using react-thunk)

```jsx
const submit = (url, data) => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ type: 'submit-start' });

  return new Promise((res, rej) => 
    fetch(/*do some stuff*/)
      .then(res => {
        if (res.status !== 200) {
          dispatch({ type: 'submit-err' })
          //the object which is rejected here
          //configures the errors displayed in the form
          //in best case your server delivers an appropriate
          //response
          rej({ _error: 'Validation Failed', age: 'too young' });

        } else {
          dispatch({ type: 'submit-success' });
          res(res.json())
        }

      })
  );
}

export { submit };
```

and in the component:

```jsx
submit (data) {
  return this.props.submit(<url>, data)
}

render () {
  const { handleSubmit } = this.props;
  return <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submit)}>…</form>
}
```

If the returned Promise from the action creator is rejected, the error message is displayed.

Redux-Thunk returns the return value of the function called with dispatch as parameter, in this case a promise.

For redux form submit validation, the submit function must return a promise, which can be resolved, or rejected.

[docs](http://redux-form.com/5.3.1/#/examples/submit-validation?_k=oflodd)

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty much what I'm already doing. What I want to do is pass an arbitrary callback into the component that is called after the fetch promise has resolved successfully. I can't just chain on to the fetch promise because I want to catch other errors, but not SubmissionErrors and working around that is messy.